# How do I switch between HTML pages in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a search bar in my web page and I'm trying to get the user input and compare it to a keyword. If it matches, show the user what he is searching for in another page.

The problem is that I don't know how to switch between pages of the HTML using JavaScript (being in `page1.html` and then take the user to `page2.html` if the keyword matches).

I've tried to implement `href` to a function and then running it when the search button is pressed but I haven't found a way to do it.

**Here is the code:**

```
<script>
   let search = getElementById("Search").value;
   if (search == "Keyword") {
      //a href="page2.html" - (this is was my main idea, but i haven't found a way to implement it correctly) 
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to get the value from the input that you create and then you have to compare between the value that you get it and the specific keyword that you want, and after that, you have to create a button to submit with it. Then you can try this line

```
window.location.href=“./Page2.htm”;
```

inside if condetion.

Comment: Is it `page.htm` or that's just a typo for `./page2.html`?

Answer (score 1):

try with:
`window.location.href=“./Page2.htm”;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
window.open(stringURL);
```

to open the html in a new window.

To open a new tab:

```
window.open(stringURL, “_blank”);
```

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open